# SQL query: Concatination of columns in sql : Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table with the following data:

```
col-1   col-2   col-3   col-4   col-5   col-6   col-7
-----   -----   -----   -----   -----   -----   -----
10      2       30      13      A       0.1     0.3
10      2       30      13      B       0.2     0.9
10      2       30      13      C       0.8     0.7
10      2       30      13      D       0.4     0.5
2       1       8       11      A       0.3     0.4
2       1       8       11      B       0.9     0.2
2       1       8       11      C       0.1     0.8
2       1       8       11      D       0.2     0.5
```

I have to come up with the following table: (here col-1 to col-4 have same values for 4 different values of col-5)

```
col-1    col-2    col-3    col-4    A_6    B_6    C_6    D_6    A_7    B_7  
-----    -----    -----    -----    ---    ---    ---    ---    ---    ---  
10        2         30      13      0.1    0.2    0.8    0.4    0.3    0.9  
2         1         8       11      0.3    0.9    0.1    0.2    0.4    0.2
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

**Consider** A_6 as A_COL_6 means Col_6 Value for A

Comment: Google for "pivot query SQL," or look into using [the PIVOT operator](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php) in Oracle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH
    temp_t
    AS
        (SELECT '10'     col_1,
                '2'      col_2,
                '30'     col_3,
                '13'     col_4,
                'A'      col_5,
                0.1      col_6,
                0.3      col_7
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '10', '2', '30', '13', 'B', 0.2, 0.9 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '10', '2', '30', '13', 'C', 0.8, 0.7 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '10', '2', '30', '13', 'D', 0.4, 0.5 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '2', '1', '8', '11', 'A', 0.3, 0.4 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '2', '1', '8', '11', 'B', 0.9, 0.2 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '2', '1', '8', '11', 'C', 0.1, 0.8 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '2', '1', '8', '11', 'D', 0.2, 0.5 FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
  FROM temp_t
       PIVOT (SUM (col_6) AS c6, SUM (col_7) AS c7
             FOR (col_5)
             IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))
```

Comment: That's it - just remove single quotes for COL_6 (as they cause *invalid number*).

Comment: @Hasan Alizada, what needs to be the changed for the two output columns (see the modified question), thanks for ur help

Comment: Thanks for your support, @hasan , It would be really helpful if you can explain it's working in brief.

Comment: Welcome, @SurendraSingh. To be honest, syntax is very basic and simple - just aggregates values and converts to columns. Also, see here: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CASE WHEN` expression with *Aggregate function*

```
WITH T AS(
     SELECT '10'  col_1,'2'   col_2,'30'  col_3,'13' col_4,'A'  col_5, '0.1'  col_6,'0.3' col_7 FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT '10', '2', '30', '13', 'B', '0.2','0.9' FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT '10', '2', '30', '13', 'C', '0.8','0.7' FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT '10', '2', '30', '13', 'D', '0.4','.5' FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT '2' ,'1' ,'8' ,'11','A' , '0.3','0.4'   FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT '2', '1', '8', '11', 'B', '0.9','0.2'   FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT '2', '1', '8', '11', 'C', '0.1','0.8'   FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT '2', '1', '8', '11', 'D', '0.2','0.5'   FROM DUAL
 )
 SELECT COL_1,
        COL_2,
        COL_3,
        COL_4,
        MAX(CASE WHEN COL_5 = 'A' THEN COL_6 ELSE '0' END) A_6,
        MAX(CASE WHEN COL_5 = 'B' THEN COL_6 ELSE '0' END) B_6,
        MAX(CASE WHEN COL_5 = 'C' THEN COL_6 ELSE '0' END) C_6,
        MAX(CASE WHEN COL_5 = 'D' THEN COL_6 ELSE '0' END) D_6,
        MAX(CASE WHEN COL_5 = 'A' THEN COL_7 ELSE '0' END) A_7,
        MAX(CASE WHEN COL_5 = 'B' THEN COL_7 ELSE '0' END) B_7
 FROM T
 GROUP BY 
        COL_1,
        COL_2,
        COL_3,
        COL_4
```

SQLFIDDLE:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b9bb1/21

Comment: @Surendra Singh I saw you add some sample data, but your can also use `CASE WHEN` expression with `Aggregate function` directly, I edit my sql answer and sqlfiddle

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I am getting ORA-01722: invalid number, any idea what went wrong here? seems data type issue. FYI: col_6 and col_7 are of varchar type.

Comment: I already tried this way, it reports the same error. FYI: the column value consists of temperature in Fahrenheit and column type is of varchar2. The concerned column has NULL values as well (this might be the cause of the issue) or is there a way to find what value under the column causing the ORA-01722?

Comment: @SurendraSingh Can you post your table schema to us? Because If there is a `null` column could be work http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9c54a9/1